# Get next content of text in <b> tag

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm curious whether is there a way to get only the last text in `font` tag.

```
<font face="Arial, Helvetica" size="5">
            No previous.<br><br>
            <b>Number :</b> 1</font>
```

Something like this:

```
soup.find('b',text='Number :').find_next_content
```

> Output: u' 1'

Comment: Do you want the final text in a `<font>` tag, or do you want the text that follows a `<b>`? In this case they are the same, but which question are you really asking?

Answer (score 1):

To get the text that immediately follows the `<b>` element:

```
In [18]: soup.find('b', text='Number :').next_sibling
Out[18]: ' 1'
```

To get the final text inside the `<font>` element:

```
In [24]: soup.find('font').contents[-1]
Out[24]: ' 1'
```

Sample Program:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = '''<font face="Arial, Helvetica" size="5">
            No previous.<br><br>
            <b>Number :</b> 1</font>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup)

result0 = soup.find('b', text='Number :').next_sibling
result1 = soup.find('font').contents[-1]
assert(result0 == ' 1')
assert(result1 == ' 1')
```